# Python selenium: How to check for multiple elements at once

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a code in selenium to login to a website and check the response to determine whether we are successfully logged in or not. I wrote the following code to achieve it

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    def handle_response(self):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='s-btn s-btn-primary s-btn--block enterEmailComponent-button']"))) # 2 fa login
            return True
        except TimeoutException:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-autocomplete-input']"))) # normal login
                return True
            except TimeoutException:
                    return False
```

The following code works fine though it first checks for `first element` (2 fa login) then use `try & expect` block to check `2nd element` (normail-login) which takes too much time.

I was just curious if i could make `both the checks simultaneously` and return the value from the one that succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try to use `any` function:

```
def handle_response(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
            lambda driver: any(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='s-btn s-btn-primary s-btn--block enterEmailComponent-button']"))(driver),
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-autocomplete-input']"))(driver)
            )
        )
        return True
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
```

It will return `True` when one of the conditions is ok.